Why does my program exit after handling the EOFError instead of running the code inside the exception?
I want to print out a dictionary's contents after the user inputs ctrl-d, and while the program handles the exception for the EOFError, it doesn't carry out the code inside the exception.
my code is:
grocery_list = {}
while True:
    try:
        item = input("")
        for product in grocery_list:
            if item.strip().lower() == product:
                grocery_list[product] += 1
            else:
                grocery_list[item.strip().lower()] = 1
    except EOFError:
        for product in grocery_list:
            print(f"{grocery_list[product]} {product.upper()}")
        exit()


this is the code i particularly need executed
        for product in grocery_list:
            print(f"{grocery_list[product]} {product.upper()}")

i expected something like:
1 APPLE
2 BANANA
1 SUGAR

once the user inputs ctrl-d if the user entered apple once, banana twice, and sugar once prior.
but upon hitting ctrl-d the program just ends
strangely enough, when i just print within the exception
    except EOFError:
        print("x")
        exit()

it does carry out and prints
x
could anyone explain?

When you print out grocery_list on its own, does it contain what you expect it to? (Also, why are you iterating over a dictionary to update one item in it?)

In the try block, this loop for product in grocery_list: never executes, because grocery_list is empty.

And even if grocery_list were not empty, it would be wrong. For every item in the grocery list with a different name, you'll set the quantity of the entered item back to 1.

Your logic is incorrect for updating the dictionary. Consider the following:
grocery_list = {}
while True:
    for product in grocery_list:
        ...

There are no items in grocery_list so the for loop is going to be a no-op. You then have this wrapped in a while True loop, which is going to run forever, doing nothing on each of its iterations.
Another issue with this code is that you put the try/except blocks within the for loop. You use a call to exit() to escape the loop in the exception handler, but you could simply move the try/except and avoid needing to manually exit.

What you probably want to use is a defaultdict, which will initialize values to a sane default when you access the dictionary with a key not yet assigned. defaultdict(int) will set the value for a key to 0 when accessed for a missing key, and otherwise return the stored value.
from collections import defaultdict

grocery_list = defaultdict(int)
try:
    while True:
        item = input("")
        product = item.strip().lower()
        grocery_list[product] += 1
except EOFError:
    for product in grocery_list:
        print(f"{grocery_list[product]} {product.upper()}")


It's not going to loop forever. It will loop zero times, and not do anything.

Right. I thought you were talking about for product in grocery_list:.

What's confusing is that you say the infinite loop is because the grocery list is empty.

The real problem with the while loop is that it's outside the try rather than inside. You fixed that in your code, but didn't explain it.

@Barmar Fair point. Updated again.

thank you! i am horribly inexperienced and in hindsight should have actually looked more into appending to a dictionary. much appreciated that you fixed my blunder

@karp Glad to have helped! Highly recommend using an IDE with a debugger so you can add breakpoints and manually walk through each line as it's running. It will allow you to inspect the application state after each line and make it much more obvious what is happening.
